# What is the extra /kafka on the zookeeper address? Why create topics this way?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I should create a topic by

```
sh /opt/client/Kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24002/kafka --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --topic order
```

in kafka rather than

```
sh /opt/client/Kafka/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:24002 --create --partitions 3 --replication-factor 1 --topic order
```

Why does the true way have one more word "/kafka"?

Answer (score 0):

The `/kafka` on Zookeeper is called a chroot. It acts like a folder in Zookeeper for isolation of data. You'd need to ask your server administrators why they did it this way

Worth mentioning, Zookeeper flag is deprecated in latest Kafka.

Also, you should place the Kafka installation bin folder on your PATH so that you don't need to always use the full file path.